# From a time cell and a percent cell for historical graph in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a stock spreadsheet showing both the performance of individual stock and also of the entire portfolio. I have the stock price automatically pulled from Yahoo! finance, continuously updated during the day.

Let's say my portfolio is worth 1000 USD. After one day my stocks have gone up 10%, so my portfolio is now worth 1100 USD. What I'm looking for is a line graph that can automatically record this, with the date and the change in %. Something like this:

https://www.screencast.com/t/rxUz2nDHeN2

The cell with the portfolio value updates every second but I don't need a graph that is that detailed, freezing the value once or twice a day at a given time would be fine!

What would be the best way to go about this? The simplest way would be being able to automatically copy the value from the "Portfolio Value"-cell to another column once a day, together with today's date, and then making a graph from that data but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: you can try to wrap it in =IF statement with =TODAY & =TIME to get an update once a day and then run some script to copy values from a range